# Joining point data in chronological order using timestamp in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polyline-creation, points-to-line, order, timestamp

I have a data set which gives me the location of livestock every 30 minutes over months. I want to join these points to show the path travelled by individual animals. I have a unique ID for each animal and a timestamp for each data point.

Comment: Could you show us what your data looks like (screenshot of part of the attribute table)?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to QGIS @Eleanor. Try the algorithm `Vector Creation` -> `Points to Path` in the processing toolbox. Then specify your timestamp and uniqueID fields as the "order" and "group" parameters:

[image]